# How to remove recyclerview item from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with Linear recycler view with items in it. Clicking on it takes to another activity which shows the detailed content of recycler view item. I want to delete recycler view item from recycler view when delete button is clicked in this activity.

my code: (crashing)

```
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                source.deleteBookmark(feeId);
                adapter = new BookmarkAdapter(context);
                adapter.deleteItem(position);
                ((Activity) context).finish();
   }
```

code in deleteItem of adapter

```
public void deleteItem(int position)
{
    bookmarks.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Comment: use startActivity for Result. In onActivityResult delete item and refresh recyclerview

Comment: Can you plz help me with code?

Comment: google it  you will many similar examples